# irreducibility of $x^n+y^n+z^n+w^n$ in $\Bbb C[x,y,z,w]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am trying to prove $x^n+y^n+z^n+w^n$ is irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y,z,w]$. I am trying to apply the Esinsten's theorem, that some prime $p$ in $\Bbb C[y,z,w]$ divides $y^n+z^n+w^n$, but $p^2$ does not. I can find such prime $y-\frac{e^{i\pi}}{n} z$ in $\Bbb C[y,z]$, which divides $y^n+z^n$ since $(\frac{e^{i\pi}}{n}z)^n=-z^n $, but $(y-\frac{e^{i\pi}}{n} z)^2$ does not divides $y^n+z^n$(I cannot show this), therefore, Esinstein's theorem can be applyed to $x^n+y^n+z^n.$ But I cannot find such prime for $x^n+y^n+z^n+w^n$ to apply the Esinstein's theorem.

Comment: If $x^n+y^n+z^n+w^n$ was reducible, note that none of its factors can be purely in terms of $w$, otherwise $P(w)$ is a factor and we can choose a root $w=w_1$, which will force $x^n+y^n+z^n+w_1^n=0$ for all $x,y,z$. Then we could set $w=0$ and obtain a factorization for $x^n+y^n+z^n$ case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element $w \in \mathbb C[x,y,z,w]$ is prime. It is well-known that if the image of $f = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2$ in $\mathbb C[x,y,z,w]/(w) = \mathbb C[x,y,z]$ is irreducible, then so is $f$. But you have already shown that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$.

Comment: Thank you very much!